# Can't get gdal_calc.py to work

Tags: qgis, python, raster, gdal

I am new to python and QGIS (have some experience with arcpy). I am trying to multiply two .tif files together using gdal_calc.py but I can't get it to work. It just returns the error invalid syntax. Here is the code. I am doing this in the QGIS Python command line.

```
gdal_calc.py -A people.tif -B places.tif --outfile=c:/test.tif --calc="A*B" --NoDataValue=0
```

I then tried this after reading an answer to another question, which ran and printed a number. However, it has not output a .tif file:

```
import os

gdal_calc =  'python C:/wheregdal_calc/islocated -Apeople.tif B-places.tif --outfile=c:/test.tif --calc="A*B"'
os.system(gdal_calc)
```

Comment: B-places.tif should be -B places

Comment: thankyou for your response, changed this and still get the same result, a number prints but no output file is created

Comment: make sure you use a space before the filenames  e.g. `-A people.tif -B places.tif` in the python version, same as the command line